# How to replace a char with another char without using string.replace?

Tags: c#, string, replace, find

I want to find all occurrences of a char for ex. "H" inside of a longer string "The Haunting of Hill House". I am using this code but I am only searching by a specific position.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "The Haunting of Hill House!";
       Console.WriteLine("String: " + str);
        // replacing character at position 7
        int pos = 7;
        char rep = 'p';


            string res = str.Substring(0, pos) + rep + str.Substring(pos + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("String after replacing a character: " + res);
            Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Why you can’t use string.Replace() ?

Comment: @BasilKosovan because that's how the task is and that's how I have to implement, I already stated that I should not use replace().

Comment: @bimixbimix, I updated my answer, kindly look into it.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I want to find all 'H' occurrences and change all of them with 'p'.

Comment: You can look into my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Line solution using Linq without using `string.Replace()`,

```
string result = string.Join("", str.Select(x => x == 'H' ? 'p' : x));
                                                       `
```

If you want to replace whole string then try this

```
string result1 = string.Join(" ", str.Split(' ').Select(x => x == "Hill" ? "Zill" : x));
```

Input:

```
The Haunting of Hill House!
```

Output:

```
The paunting of pill pouse!

The Haunting of Zill House!
              //^^^^ Replaced word from Hill to Zill
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uyRqMW)

Comment: He want to replace string from other string not char from other string

Comment: @AiverReaver, Hey check updated answer, now my answer supports replacement of **string**. Look into my answer

Comment: @AiverReaver, Kindly look into comment provided by OP, he clearly mentioned he want to replace H with p i.e replacing `char` with another `char`

Comment: It only supports the replacement of words separated by spaces.  `string.Replace` works on any substring.  `"Hello".Replace("He", "Ro")` would give "Rollo" but your code would not.

Comment: @juharr, your scenario is challenging to replace without `string.replace()` in **single line of linq**, but my answer supports what OP's expectations

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar sorry I was mistaken, here is the example I want to implement: For instance, given the string “Something” if you were to replace all occurrences of “so” with “DMS” the result would be “DMSmething”. How can I implement that?

Comment: Can you answer my latest question?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar alright I am sorry but I thought you were ignoring me. Here is the link to the new question, if possible please answer it, I would highly appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56915375/given-a-string-find-occurances-and-replace-with-another-string-without-using-str?noredirect=1#comment100373655_56915375

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar now why dont you take a look to my other question?

Comment: @bimixbimix, sorry dude it is already 10:30PM + here , I need to sleep, Hope you will good answer for your question.

Comment: you sleep so early

Answer (score 0):

The general approach first find the string position you want to replace on other string with `String.IndexOf` function then slice the string from the position to length of string you want to replace than just insert the string with `string.insert` function.

Comment: Can it replace string? your solution only replaces one char.

Comment: Could you please provide implementation, instead of just statement, I will upvote if you provide correct implementation with fiddle