# Given a string find occurrences and replace with another string without using string.replace()

Tags: c#, string, replace, char

Here is an example of what I want to implement: for instance, given the string `Something`, if you were to replace all occurrences of `so` with `DDD`, the result would be `DDDmething`.

Here is how I am implementing it; my code finds a char by its specific position and changes it, but in fact I want to implement what I stated above.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "The Haunting of Hill House!";
        Console.WriteLine("String: " + str);

        // replacing character at position 7
        int pos = 7;
        char rep = 'p';

        string res = str.Substring(0, pos) + rep + str.Substring(pos + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("String after replacing a character: " + result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: All you need to add is essentially a call to `int index = str.IndexOf(<your search string>)` and then some math to figure out how much of the old string to copy in the `substring` calls.

Comment: You mean something like `Regex.Replace(input, Regex.Escape(searchString), replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`?

Comment: Why don't you just use String.Replace() method? I mean what's the problem?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError can you please show an implementation of that?

Comment: @Sweeper I cant use replace

Comment: I could, but it's more fun for you to work it out yourself.

Comment: @GauravMall because that's how the requirement of the task is

Comment: @500-InternalServerError why do you think I have posted a question here if I would know how to do it?!

Comment: I just asked. Chill. Wanted to ask if you were having any problem with the replace() function.

Comment: So then I could have helped you, but now we need to think of a new implementation.

Comment: @GauravMall dude maybe you should chill. I just answered your question normally!

Comment: I did too. It's not to offend you. Let's be friendly :)

Comment: I am being friendly but you started unfortunately, I wasn't writing with a tone.

Comment: @GauravMall can you upvote my question so others can see and answer?

Comment: Of course, I can

Comment: BTW, if the task specifically mentions the `String.Replace` method as in the title, then @Sweeper's suggestion is technically valid as `Regex.Replace` is not `String.Replace`

Comment: @Slai Yea but still I cant use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative might be to split the string by "so" and join the resulting array by "DDD" :

```
string result = string.Join("DDD", "something".Split(new[] { "so" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Comment: it shows an error " cannot convert from string[] to char.

Comment: How can I count how many changes have been made aka how many occurrences have been found?

Comment: @bimixbimix `.Length - 1` of the array result from `.Split`

Comment: I tried `var count = array.Length - 1;` but it prints 32 which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  The idea is to use `IndexOf` to find the index of the substring to replace then append the substring before it followed by the replacement, then start the search over from the end of the found substring.  Then after all substrings are found and replaced append the rest of the original string to the end if there is any.

Note this doesn't do any checks on the input and you really should use the `string.Replace` as I'm sure it's more performant.

```
public string Replace(string input, string find, string replace)
{
    // The current index in the string where we are searching from
    int currIndex = 0;

    // The index of the next substring to replace
    int index = input.IndexOf(find);

    // A string builder used to build the new string
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Continue until the substring is not found
    while(index != -1)
    {
        // If the current index is not equal to the substring location
        // when we need to append everything from the current position
        // to where we found the substring
        if(index != currIndex ) 
        {
            builder.Append(input.Substring(currIndex , index - currIndex));
        }

        // Now append the replacement
        builder.Append(replace);

        // Move the current position past the found substring
        currIndex = index + find.Length;

        // Search for the next substring.
        index = input.IndexOf(find, currIndex );
    }

    // If the current position is not the end of the string we need
    // to append the remainder of the string.
    if(currIndex < input.Length) 
    {
        builder.Append(input.Substring(currIndex));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this, where is the string declared?

Comment: can you take an actual example and print it out?

Comment: It's a method and you'd use it like `string result = Replace("some sort of something", "so", "da");` to get "dame dart of damething".

Comment: thanks but I think I will go with @Slai answer as it is only of line of code.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:

```
var someString = "This is some sort of string.";

var resultIndex = 0;
var searchKey ="So";
var replacementString = "DDD";
while ((resultIndex = someString.IndexOf(searchKey, resultIndex, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1)
{
  var prefix = someString.Substring(0, Math.Max(0, resultIndex - 1));
  var suffix = someString.Substring(resultIndex + searchKey.Length);
  someString = prefix + replacementString + suffix;
  resultIndex += searchKey.Length;
}
```

Expected to produce *"This is DDDme DDDrt of string."*.

Comment: You meant `someString.IndexOf(searchKey, resultIndex)` not `string.IndexOf` because it's an instance method.  Also with that fixed it gives the result "DDDme sort of string".  And finally it would be much better to use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings in a loop.

Comment: yes, my bad. i fixed it. StringBuilder is overkill for this. Performance wise.

Comment: If you run that now it fails when `resultIndex` is 0 then `Math.Min(0, resultIndex - 1)` is -1 which is and invalid length to pass to `Substring`.

Comment: Yes. I didn't checked or tested it. It's supposed to be `Math.Max` instead. I fixed it . Thank you!

Comment: Neede some copy and paste fix too. Replaced the search variable

Comment: Now it works. Sorry, I didn't tested it. Now I tested it online.

Comment: yea but still if I try to print someString it prints multiple times depending in how many occurrences it has made the changes.